# Erro de syntax do ES2015

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Desenvolvi um pacote npm usando preset do es2015 em ambiente local funcionou muito bem o pacote pois eu estava rodando babel-node index.js.

Quando eu publiquei ela no npm e instalei em um projeto para testar.
Usando ela da seguinte forma:

```
import ValidateFlag from 'validate-flag';
```

ele já retorna um erro interno na lib falando da syntax pq eu usei import e export default para desenvolver.

Nesse projeto no que eu usei pra testar eu tbm estou com o preset do es2015

erro na lib

```
C:\Users\joao\Desktop\ol\node_modules\validate-flag\main.js:54
export default Cartoes;
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

E tbm da erro nos imports

Erro ao adicionar `"type":"module"`

```
C:\Users\joao\Desktop\ol>npm test

> ol@1.0.0 test
> babel-node index.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119
      throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath);
      ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM] [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\joao\Desktop\ol\node_modules\validate-flag\main.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of C:\Users\joao\Desktop\ol\node_modules\validate-flag\main.js from C:\Users\joao\Desktop\ol\index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename main.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\Users\joao\Desktop\ol\node_modules\validate-flag\package.json.

    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:278:15)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:13)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (C:\Users\joao\Desktop\ol\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:807:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:991:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:/Users/joao/Desktop/ol/index.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1102:14)
    at loader (C:\Users\joao\Desktop\ol\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\joao\Desktop\ol
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c babel-node index.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\joao\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-03T22_14_12_110Z-debug.log

C:\Users\joao\Desktop\ol>
```

Esse diretório ol é onde eu estou testando a minha lib como se eu fosse um usuário

Comment: `um erro interno na lib falando da syntax` O que lhe disse?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, coloquei o erro la

Answer (score -3):

A lib é para NodeJs ou Javascript?

Se for para node tente usar `module.exports = Cartoes;` ao invés de `export default Cartões;`

Answer (score -4):

```
C:\Users\joao\Desktop\ol\node_modules\validate-flag\main.js:54
export default Cartoes;
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

Isto quer dizer que `C:\Users\joao\Desktop\ol\node_modules\validate-flag\package.json` falta a linha `"type": "module"`

Comment: Ao adicionar o type: ``` "type":"module" ``` gerou o seguinte erro, vou editar a pergunta com o erro atual